# iOS-QR-Code-Generator linking issue

Tags: ios, qr-code

Need to generate QR code from iOS for different strings. Tried out the following library:

```
**jverkoey-ObjQREncoder-e1841fe**
```

being able to generate QR Code .. but this code cannot be read by any readers.

```
**iOS-QR-Code-Generator**
```

Following the documentation provided But facing linking problem when i am trying to add the 'kuapay-iOS-QR-Code-Generator' to generate QRCode.  I followed the way that is written in the github project

"To build your own project from this template you must attace the libz.dylib library to your target in Xcode.  You must also drag the QRDraw and libpng folder files into your project.  Update the Header Search path to look in the libpng folder in your target build settings menu."

But it give me 6 error message. These are -

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "CQR_Encode::EncodeData(int, int, bool, int, char*, int)", referenced from:
      -[RootViewController LoadQRImage] in RootViewController.o
  "CQR_Encode::~CQR_Encode()", referenced from:
      -[RootViewController LoadQRImage] in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FileManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
  "QRDrawPNG::draw(char*, int, int, unsigned char (*) [177], void*)", referenced from:
      -[RootViewController LoadQRImage] in RootViewController.o
  "CQR_Encode::CQR_Encode()", referenced from:
      -[RootViewController LoadQRImage] in RootViewController.o
  "vtable for QRDrawPNG", referenced from:
      QRDrawPNG::QRDrawPNG() in RootViewController.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help me with this? OR suggest a better QRcode generator for iOS device?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because you are using c++ code silently in your app , use `.mm` instead of `.m`  in your `RootViewController` .

Comment: check if you have added all the required frameworks and libraries and target dependencies in your project. I think you are missing QuartzCore.Framework or  "libqrencoder.a" in libraries and also check in target dependencies you have "qrencoder" in your project.

Comment: Okay, i figured out that the problem is happening when i am using kuapay_iOS-QR-Code-Generator and zxing decoder code at the same project. is it possible to send you the project? or the only way to share it would be github?

Comment: You can use both zxing and kuapay_iOS-QR-Code-Generator in same project , just make sure you have added the libraries , frameworks, targets and header paths correctly .I have recently done the same in my project few days ago. You can share your zip file upload anywhere and give me the link .

Comment: Figured out the solution. zxing was done in 3.2 and kuapay in 4.2. So it wasn't working in the same project. Converted zxing to 4.2 and then it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the file Barcode.mm, qr_draw_png.mm, QR_Encode.mm linked to your project target. Also you may be add "-fno-objc-arc" flag.